# Isset not working with post method

Tags: php, mysql, post, isset

Simple code working correctly:
Form:

```
<form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="betterplace.php">
<input type="file" name="delhi" required="required" value="delhi" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
</form>
Action:
$mumbai=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$sql = " SELECT xyz FROM `dataperiod` WHERE cities LIKE '$mumbai' ";
if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']');
}
/do the stuff
```

But for making empty property,i assigned isset code to this like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
$mumbai=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$sql = " SELECT xyz FROM `dataperiod` WHERE cities LIKE '$mumbai' ";
if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']');
}
/do the stuff
}
else{  
    header('location: home.php'); exit();
}
?>
```

But nothing showing or working.I think problem is not taking post element.Please help.

Comment: if you open this link in chrome, do you see any error "infinite page forwarding"??  Its because $_POST will be always set. @ankhzet is answered to this.

Comment: @SubinThomas, doubt that, scripts/redirects placed at different locations (`betterplace.php` and `home.php`) and it looks like page with form also doesn't contains auto-redirect stuff. If `header('location: home.php'); exit();`-line is itself placed in `home.php`, than yes, possible circular redirect, but `post` request points to `action="betterplace.php"`

Answer (score 0):

Do `onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();"` firing and redirect to `betterplace.php` occurs?

Anyway, `isset($_POST)` is wrong, `$_POST` is *always* set, but can be empty, so, as files are always transferred via `POST/PUT`, you need just something like:

```
if (isset($_FILES['delphi'])) {
    ...
}
```

Look closer at `$_FILES['delphi']`. Yours file input named `delphi`, not `image` (as u assumed in `mumbai=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];`):

```
<input type="file" name="delhi" ... >
```

So, finally:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['delphi']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['delphi']['tmp_name'])) {
        $mumbai = $_FILES['delphi']['tmp_name'];
        ...
    }
```

Or:

```
<?php
    if (is_uploaded_file($mumbai = @$_FILES['delphi']['tmp_name'])) {
        ...
    }
```